# linux on rk3566 (vontar kk max)

Tags: linux, arm

Понадобилось мне на android tv приставку linux поставить, перепробовал много разных дистрибутивов под rk3566, но ничего толкового не нашёл, один armbian от station m2 (мини пк какой-то) хоть что-то выдал, но в виде ошибки "Failed Link SPIe".

Вроде как [этот](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/arm/juno) может подойти, но, что за непонятные слова и команды там написаны, мне не понятно. Могу предположить, что это команды из linux.

Кто подкован в этой теме, подкиньте загрузочный `.img` файл под этот процессор (rk3566). Ато уже перерыл все источники, в которых хоть что-то было понятно для обывателя.

Приставка "Vontar KK Max" - 8гб ОЗУ, 64 ПЗУ.

Comment: Образ под процессор — этого недостаточно. Вам надо образ под **платформу**.

Comment: Как понять "платформу"? Архитектуру?

Comment: Вот вам и домашнее задание образовалось! Когда поймёте, то решение будет очевиден.

Comment: А вы знаете ответ?

Comment: Я обязательно почитаю, т.к. мне это интересно, но решение мне нужно как можно скорее(. Пускай Вы знаете ответ и поможете мне и для меня это будет медвежья услуга, но Я всё равно найду время, чтобы разобраться в этом, а Вы мне очень поможете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vontar KK Max на 8Gb не существует в природе. Заявленные 8Gb фейковые, настоящий размер 4gb, это видно в логе загрузки android. Подробности на 4pda в теме по Vontar KK Max, там же выкладывал armbian для SD карты и для eMMC.